# Make a route_param embedded into a resource a string

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am trying to make a route parameter embedded inside a resource as a string.

```
class Example < Grape::API
  resource 'a/:param/b' do
    # code
  end
end
```

One way I could think of is by splitting the resource into route_param blocks and make it a string but this will introduce a lot of nesting which would defeat the purpose of the resource having an embedded route_param and thereby preventing the nesting.

```
class Example < Grape::API
  resource 'a' do
    route_param :param, type: String do
      resource 'b' do
        # code
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Another way I could think of is by explicitly defining in a param block which would potentially duplicate a lot of code.

```
class Example < Grape::API
  resource 'a/:param/b' do
    params do
      requires :param,
               type: String
    end
    # code
  end
end
```

Is anybody aware of a different way? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "this will introduce a lot of nesting which would defeat the purpose of the resource having a nested route_params". I think this is a clean and clear implementation

Comment: I mean a route_param can be embedded into a resource so that we can avoid the potential deep nesting caused by using multiple nested route_param and resource paths as shown in the code snippet 2. Updated the description to make the question much it clear.

Comment: Right I am just not sure I understand your objection to this type of namespacing. Honestly it is nearly identical to the way the documentation suggests going about this. [Include Parent Namespaces](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#include-parent-namespaces)

Comment: So you mean I should add `type: String` into `param` key of declared(params) hash?